# Непонятная кодировка в результате поиска google

Tags: html, css, search

Если перейти по запросу [google](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B),  То видно, что второй запрос сайт daikon.kz описание написано какими-то крякозябрами. Сайт делал не я, но поддерживать заставили, написан на WP. Где копать?

Comment: Шрифты кастомные не используются?

Comment: да нет Tahoma показывает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если открыть исходный код страницы — увидим, что первый текст, который встречается - это `title` для плагина `prettyPhoto`. Его гугл и берет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужно решить две проблемы:

1. Поправить кодировку для плагина. И поместить его код вниз страницы.
2. Провести элементарную оптимизацию для SEO — прописать мета-теги `description` и `keywords`.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли!